# Padding too small in review queue

Tags: bug, design, review-queue

In my opinion the padding is too small in the first posts review queue between the green checkmark and the score (if answer is accepted):

[image: You don't see what I am talking about? This is because the padding too small for human eyes.]

I suppose everything would look much better if we gave the checkmark 10px margin to the top:

```
.review-task-page .vote-accepted-on.load-accepted-answer-date
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```